# React pass more than one arguments to component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

my English is not very good but i try to explain myself clear.
I have two components - `OrderInfo` and `OrderTopMenu` inside OrderInfo.
I pass through 2 arguments:

`<OrderTopMenu args  = {this.state.status} args2 = {this.state.user} />`

inside the **OrderTopMenu** i pass trough arguments like this:

```
`export default class OrderTopMenu extends Component {
       constructor(args, args2) {

       super(args, args2);

        console.log(args)
        console.log(args2)

        this.state = {
          orderInfo: args.orderInfo,
          statuses: [],
          messages: [],
          contacts: [],
          chosenContacts: [],
          files: [],
          chosenFiles: [],
          message: '',
          message_target: '',
          status_id: args.status_id,
          ins_order: args.ins_order,
          ins_type:  args.ins_type,
          lack_claims_status: args.lack_claims_status,
          readonly: true,
          target_to_send: '',
          files_required: false,
          messageChosen: false,
          auth_user: args2,
          policies: {
              comprehensive_policy_number: '',
              compulsory_policy_number: '',
          }
      }

   }
```

`

The first args i'm getting correct, but second args i see only in console log inside the constructor on `OrderTopMenu`, but when i try to access them inside the function after onClick on button after component is mount i got undefined.
Cant't figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: I would advise you to read the docs to clear the understanding of props first. https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html and https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Component class constructor params is just receive props that given JSX props.
So you should use props in constructor.
Like this.

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   let {args, args2} = props;

   console.log(args);
   console.log(args2);
}
```

OR you can use the distructring directly

constructor({args, args2}) {
       super({args, args2});

```
   console.log(args);
   console.log(args2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `props` to the constructor and access your *arguments* as `this.props.args` and `this.props.args2`

```
export default class OrderTopMenu extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    console.log(this.props.args);
    console.log(this.props.args2);

    this.state = {
      orderInfo: this.props.args.orderInfo,
      statuses: [],
      messages: [],
      contacts: [],
      chosenContacts: [],
      files: [],
      chosenFiles: [],
      message: '',
      message_target: '',
      status_id: args.status_id,
      ins_order: this.props.args.ins_order,
      ins_type:  this.props.args.ins_type,
      lack_claims_status: this.props.args.lack_claims_status,
      readonly: true,
      target_to_send: '',
      files_required: false,
      messageChosen: false,
      auth_user: this.props.args2,
      policies: {
          comprehensive_policy_number: '',
          compulsory_policy_number: '',
      }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should extract your arguments from `props` in the `OrderTopMenu` component.

Your code should be like this:

```
export default class OrderTopMenu extends Component {
       constructor(props) {

       super(props);

        console.log(props.args)
        console.log(props.args2)
       ......
```

Also from button click, you should be able to access the args from `props` using `this.props`.

```
onButtonClick = () => {
  const {args, args2} = this.props;
  console.log('argument :', args);
  console.log('argument 1:', args1);

}
```